# Problem using fsanitize on Macos Monterey 12.0.1

Tags: c, sanitizer

I can't use fsanitize on Macos every time I execute my programs this message appears:

a.out(1003,0x111253600) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.

the code work but it doesn't detect leaks anymore.
I compile with clang -fsanitize=address main.c, where main.c is just a test where I don't free my string allocated with malloc:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char    *a;

    a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);

    a[0] = 't';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 's';
    a[3] = 't';
    a[4] = '\0';
    write(1, a, strlen(a));
    return (0);
}
```

the result of this program:

a.out(1033,0x1086d8600) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.
test%

the only solution I found on the internet was to set MallocNanoZone variable to 0 but even the message doesn't appear, it still doesn't detect leaks.

Comment: Does inserting `free(a);` after the `write` change anything? (And you shouldn't cast the malloc return value; search this site for why).

Comment: inserting free(a) after write doesn't change anything, the message is still here.

Comment: What about adding `if (a == NULL) perror("Cant allocate memory");` after the `malloc()`